Left join two sorted dataframes in pyspark
I have two dataframes that are ordered by a certain column, which is also the join key.
Is it possible to merge these two dataframes returning a sorted one in O(n+m)? I don't care if its not done in parallel. I have too much data (4billion + 20million rows) and I can't use a simple events.join(t_status, on='t').sort('t')

You can merge the sorted dataframes in linear time O(n+m) as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Example dataframes sorted by "key" in ascending order
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "A"), (3, "C"), (5, "E")], ["key", "value"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(2, "B"), (4, "D"), (6, "F")], ["key", "value"])
rdd1 = df1.rdd
rdd2 = df2.rdd

def merge_sorted_rdds(rdd1, rdd2):
    # Get iterators for both RDDs
    iter1 = rdd1.collect()
    iter2 = rdd2.collect()
    
    i, j = 0, 0
    merged_result = []
    
    # Merge the two sorted RDDs
    while i < len(iter1) and j < len(iter2):
        if iter1[i][0] < iter2[j][0]:
            merged_result.append(iter1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            merged_result.append(iter2[j])
            j += 1
            
    while i < len(iter1):
        merged_result.append(iter1[i])
        i += 1
        
    while j < len(iter2):
        merged_result.append(iter2[j])
        j += 1
        
    return merged_result

merged_data = merge_sorted_rdds(rdd1, rdd2)
merged_df = spark.createDataFrame(merged_data, ["key", "value"])
merged_df.show()

# Output:
# +---+-----+
# |key|value|
# +---+-----+
# |  1|    A|
# |  2|    B|
# |  3|    C|
# |  4|    D|
# |  5|    E|
# |  6|    F|
# +---+-----+


Thank you! The algorithm is pretty straightforward, a classic from algorithms 101. It baffles me how I haven't found it in any famous data science library! It would also be trivially parallelizable by bucketing the data by key first.

It is indeed present in polars.

This solution uses .collect() and the dataset is too large to fit in memory

"I don't care if its not done in parallel." ~ stated in the question. This solution is considering that.

Memory != parallelism
